# Where can I find in PHP source files where is the code of an internal function like is_string()?

Tags: php

I already downloaded the source, and I think the code of `is_string()` is somewhere in `ext/standard/`, but I am not sure.

Comment: Well, can't you "grep" through the source files?

Comment: @WheatBeak Whilst this is in fact possible for an IDE this would require quite some setup. Not so sure if you realize that...

Comment: I find github has good search functionality. https://github.com/php/php-src

Comment: @arkascha not sure what you mean most good IDE's will have built in functionality to search multiple files...

Comment: @WheatBeak You don't need an IDE to search for a string in a bunch of files. I thought you suggest to use the IDE to follow the traceback path. Which is a bit complicated here since you'd have to correctly setup the project inside the IDE to be able to traverse the border between php scripts and c based library source files...

Comment: I tried to search by is_string, but returned too much ocurrences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ext/standard/type.c

You can also find it online:

http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git&a=search&h=HEAD&st=grep&s=%28is_string%29

Edit to add:
You can find different version by replacing the h key with e.g.:
h=refs%2Fheads%2FPHP-5.6.31

PHP5 uses fewer macros than PHP7, so it looks more like normal C.

Comment: Good way to improve your knowledge of PHP or any other language too. Browse the code of a good open source project in your language. Want to learn how people use PHP's SPL patterns, search github.

Comment: I'm sorry this might be ridicules question, Is this C ?! is PHP written In C ?

Comment: Yes. The PHP interpreter is written in C.

Comment: Quick addition if a search on the function name yields too many results: all functions that are available from PHP, are created from the original source code by the `PHP_FUNCTION` macro. So if you want to find the `is_string` function, search for `PHP_FUNCTION(is_string)`. That should only give you a single result.